# Java 8 | Parallel Stream for a HashMap

Tags: java, foreach, lambda, parallel-processing, hashmap

In java 8 I know that they added the parallel stream which takes advantage of multicore processors, and I know that you can use it with something like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.parallelStream().forEach(str -> System.out.println(str));
```

But how would I achieve something like this with a HashMap?

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
// won't work, because the Map class doesn't have the .parallelStream()
map.parallelStream().forEach((str, num) -> System.out.println(str + ":" + num));
```

Does anyone know how to do something like this? Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can't stream a `Map` directly, but you can stream its entry set, given with [the `entrySet()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--).  Extract the key and value from the entry object.

```
map.entrySet()
   .parallelStream()
   .forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue()));
```

Comment: yeah but wouldn't invoking the the `.getValue()` decrease preformance?

Comment: Compared to what?  Some piece of code has to extract the value (and the key) from the entry.

Comment: @John S.: maybe you are confusing `Map.Entry.getValue` with `Map.get`. Invoking `getValue` here is not identical to a `Map` lookup. While it is map implementation dependent, an entry usually represents some sort of resolved mapping having cheap `getKey` and `getValue` methods, i.e. in case of `java.util.HashMap`, we’re talking about reading a field from the entry instance, not about a hash lookup.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the 'entry set' from the hash map by calling map.entrySet(), you can call parallelStream() on the returned entry set.

Please note that the returned object is a set of Map.Entry. You can get the key and value from an entry set item by calling getKey() and getValue() on it respectively. As follows:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("a", 1);
map.put("b", 2);
map.entrySet().parallelStream().forEach((e) -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue()));
```